# How to add logs in asp.net vNext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core

I need to set up logs in my asp.net application. It's easy to add output to the console, but I need to configure it in Azure. I don't know how to do it. I need to log all information that occurs with my app into some file and read it.

Comment: What language is your mvc website in?

Comment: Did you try to use the NLog provider ?

Comment: [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) can write in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ILoggerFactory`](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/1308245d2c470fcf437299331b8175e2e417af04/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/ILoggerFactory.cs) allows an app to use any implementation of [`ILogger`](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/1308245d2c470fcf437299331b8175e2e417af04/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/ILogger.cs) and [`ILoggerProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/5748f5d09f84796432afc1d997630c56d315cc6a/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/ILoggerProvider.cs).

For details on how to implement the interfaces properly, look at the framework's [`ConsoleLogger`](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/1308245d2c470fcf437299331b8175e2e417af04/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/ConsoleLogger.cs) and [`ConsoleLoggerProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/1308245d2c470fcf437299331b8175e2e417af04/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/ConsoleLoggerProvider.cs). See also the [ASP.NET Core documentation on logging](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/logging.html).

Here is a minimal example of a custom `ILogger` to get started. **This is not production code**, rather, it demos enough technical depth either to write your own `ILogger` or to use one from the community.

**project.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
}
```

**MyLoggingProvider.cs**

```
namespace LoggingExample
{
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

    public class MyLoggingProvider : ILoggerProvider
    {
        public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
        {
            return new MyLogger();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // TODO Cleanup
        }
    }
}
```

**MyLogger.cs**

In Azure you will  want to write to somewhere other than `C:/temp/some-guid.txt`. This is enough to get you started, though, with writing your own simple logger.

```
namespace LoggingExample
{
    using System;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

    public class MyLogger : ILogger
    {
        public void Log(LogLevel logLevel, int eventId, object state,
            Exception exception, Func<object, Exception, string> formatter)
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            if (formatter != null) {
                builder.AppendLine(formatter(state, exception));
            }

            var values = state as ILogValues;
            if (values != null) {
                foreach (var v in values.GetValues()) {
                    builder.AppendLine(v.Key + ":" + v.Value);
                }
            }

            var logPath = string.Format("C:/temp/{0}.txt", Guid.NewGuid());
            File.WriteAllText(logPath, builder.ToString());
        }

        public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel) {
            return true;
        }

        public IDisposable BeginScopeImpl(object state) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

Now in startup you can use add your logger via `loggerFactory.AddProvider(new MyLoggingProvider())`. Every call to the `ILogger` will now log with your provider.

```
namespace LoggingExample
{
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(
            IApplicationBuilder app, 
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory
                .AddConsole(minLevel: LogLevel.Verbose)
                .AddProvider(new MyLoggingProvider());

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("CatchAll");
                logger.LogInformation("Hello logger!");

                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world!");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**MyController.cs**

Anywhere that supports dependency injection can now receive an `ILogger` that will log to all of the providers that we registered in the `Startup.Configure` method.

```
namespace LoggingExample
{
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        public MyController(ILogger logger)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("Logging from my controller");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Log4Net

Use Log4Net.  Its a common framework for logging that everyone who follows up on your code will understand, and it lets you do things like attach a new log "destination" on the fly just by editing your config file.  It already covers most of the things you'll want to do (like create a separate file for each "day"), and most of the log mining tools out there will be able to read the files l4n creates.

**Setting it Up**

There are [tutorials online](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42354/The-Art-of-Logging) for how to get started, but they basically require a few simple steps:

1. **Download** the [Log4Net nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/).
2. [**Adjust** the log settings in your web.config file](http://haacked.com/archive/2005/03/07/ConfiguringLog4NetForWebApplications.aspx/)
3. **Create** a static instance of the [logger object](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-5-Using-Logger-Objects.aspx)
4. **Log Stuff** wherever you need to.  If you decide you want your logger to write to a file, it will.  If you add a database writer, it will write to the db too.  Want your log entries to show up in console, just add that logger in your default (debug) config.

Once you get it setup, logging is as simple as this code:

```
...
} catch(SystemException ex) {
   logger.Error("This error was thrown by the XXX routine", ex);
}
```

Hope that's helpful.

**Edit:  Config File + Core**

As @auga points out in his oh-so-helpful comment, config for ASP.Net 5 may require you to read carefully the link I added under step #2 above (configuring your logger).  Instead of re-writing someone else's blog post, I'll just [link to the article I used](http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2015/11/09/asp-net-5-logging-with-log4net/) to set this up in our ASP.NET 5 environment.  Works really well.

If you're reading this post to learn (instead of skimming it to critique), I'd suggest following the links...

Comment: This question regards Asp.Net core, there isn't web.config

Comment: asp.net-mvc is a web tech, but you can change web.config to app.config (or whatever config file you decide to load up in Startup.cs).

Comment: I don't agree, there isn't app.config too in Core. web.config is used only to configure IIS web site, but `ASP.NET core`can run other web servers and OS